# How does Neo4J cypher OPTIONAL MATCH works?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran into a problem today understanding OPTIONAL MATCH clause in cypher. Let's consider this simple case:

```
CREATE (:a {type:"group"})-[:a_rel]->(:a {type: "app"})-[:b_rel]->(:b);
```

This creates 2 "a" node with different type attribute, plus one "b" node. All of them are in a simple path a-->a-->b

Then, I'm trying to match the "a" node having "group" type, connected to the other "a" node, optionaly connected to the "b" node.

So, if I run the following query, I expect it to return nothing:

```
MATCH(x:a)-->(y:a) 
where x.type = "group" 
OPTIONAL MATCH (y)-->(z:b) 
where z IS NULL 
return y
```

but it always return the second "a" node of the path, using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL on the where clause.

Could you please explain me what I do not understand here. In my real model, the second "a" node can be connected or not to the "b" node. I would like to retrieve all the one that are not connected to any "b" node.

Thanks a lot for your help

Rémi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the `MATCH` clause finds a match, the query will always return `y`.

This is because the `OPTIONAL MATCH` *does not need to match anything* in order for the query to proceed. That is why it is "OPTIONAL".

This is one way to do what you intended:

```
MATCH (x:a)-->(y:a)
WHERE x.type = "group" AND NOT (y)-->(:b)
RETURN y
```

Comment: A related knowledge base article on this: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/why-where-clause-does-not-filter/

Answer (score 1):

What OPTIONAL MATCH does is , it tries to find out patterns in the graph.If matching pattern is found that Node is returned, else it is replaced with NULL.I hope this will clear the confusion caused.