# How do I prevent a subquery from executing when an `OPTIONAL MATCH` does not return any rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using this query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n {id: "does-not-exist"})
CALL {
    RETURN "test" as inner
}
RETURN inner
```

I would expect the subquery not to be executed and the outer `RETURN` to return no results. Instead, the subquery is executed once and the return value is `"test"`. I suppose it being `OPTIONAL` causes the whole query to continue with one empty row.
My actual query looks more like this:

```
MATCH (n {id: "exists"})
CALL {
    WITH n
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m {id: "mightExist"})
    CALL {
        WITH m
        MATCH (m)--(o {id: "does-not-exist"})
        RETURN "test" as inner
    }
    RETURN inner
}
RETURN inner
```

This causes the query to return nothing as the deepest subquery does not `MATCH` anything. The deepest subquery is still called once because the behavior of `OPTIONAL MATCH`. I can't change the `OPTIONAL MATCH` to be `MATCH` because then the whole query would not return anything when that relation does not exist, even though it should.

**Essentially, I'm trying to return a nested relation of a node which may or may not exist as a relation to the root node. How can I do that?**

*Note: I'm trying to stay away from APOC as much as I can to reduce vendor lock-in, but if I absolutely must use something like `apoc.when`, I could.*

Comment: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081795/how-does-neo4j-cypher-optional-match-works) question explaining that `OPTIONAL MATCH` returns `NULL` if no rows were found. You could then use a `CASE WHEN m IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END`, but that drastically limits what you can do with the result if it is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the last `MATCH` optional, and then use `WITH` to filter the rows.
Like this:

```
MATCH (n {id: "exists"})
CALL {
    WITH n
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m {id: "mightExist"})
    CALL {
        WITH m
        OPTIONAL MATCH (m)--(o {id: "does-not-exist"})
        WITH 
        CASE WHEN m IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN m IS NOT NULL AND o IS NULL THEN m
        ELSE o END AS inner
        RETURN inner
    }
    RETURN inner
}
RETURN inner
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the `WHERE` clause? In case of `m` being `NULL`, the innermost query should not return anything.

Comment: When m is NULL, your query will return nothing, as the deeply nested query returns nothing because of MATCH, which ultimately results in whole query returning nothing. In my case, using OPTIONAL MATCH I just added the capability to manipulate the results. I have updated the answer to use CASE rather than WHERE, please check it out. @Nils